# How to filter distinct counts of text with a greater than indicator in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a report that counts stores with different types of beverages. I am trying to get a distinct count of stores that are selling 4 or more Powerade flavors and two or more Coca-Cola flavors while maintaining a count of stores that are purchashing other products (Sprite, Dr. Pepper, etc.).

My data table is `BEVSALES` and the data looks like:

```
CustomerNo     Brand     Flavor
     43         PWD    Fruit Punch 
     37      Coca-Cola    Vanilla
     43         PWD     Mixed Bry
     37      Coca-Cola    Cherry
     44        Sprite   Tropical Mix
     43         PWD     Strawberry
     43         PWD       Grape
     44      Coca-Cola    Cherry  
     17      Dr. Pepper   Cherry
```

I am trying to make the data give me a distinct count of customers with filters that have `PWD>=4` and `Coca-Cola>=2`, while keeping the customer count of Dr. Pepper and Sprite at 1 each. (1 customer purchasing PWD, 1 customer Purchasing Coca-Cola, etc.)

The best measure that I have been able to find is

> = SUMX(BEVSALES, 1*(FIND("PWD",BEVSALES[Brand],,0)))

but I don't know how to put it together so the formula counts the stores that have more than 4 PWD and 2 Coca-Cola flavors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do this in a separate query. Go to the query design and click on edit. Then chose your table and group by column `Brand` and distinctcount the column `Flavor`. The result should look like this (Maybe as a new table):

```
GroupedBrand     DistinctCountFlavor
    PWD                  4 
 Coca-Cola               2 
   Sprite                1 
 Dr. Pepper              1
```

Now you can access the distinct count of the flavors by brands. With an `IIF()` statement you can check for `>=4` at PWD and so on...